Mixed integer linear programming - connection of a directed graph
I am doing a simple optimization model of a directed graph with one source node and a couple of load nodes. Every load node connected to a source node, sometimes directly and otherwise over another load node generates different profit. The weights of the edges are representing time needed to build them. The goal of optimization is to find a sequence of connecting all nodes, in such way that maximum profit is generated during the time of building all the edges.
Does any one of you know of similar models for directed graph connection that I could use for my assignment? Thanks!
P.S. each load node can be supplied only by one source/load node. In order to supply a load node, it has to be directly or indirectly connected to the source node.


https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree
